# Why is one exhaust directed upwards?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance

This is the first Cessna Skycourier during certification. Why are the two exhausts oriented upwards?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why some airplanes have their exhaust gases vectored above the wing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/75607/1696)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rotation direction of the propellers produces a rotating slipstream.  This slipstream pushes the exaust from the (engine's) right side downward, but the exhaust on the other side would be pushed up, producing potential heat problems where it impinges on the wing (as well as depositing lots of soot).  By bending the exhaust pipe upward as you see, the exhaust on that side passes over the wing, in an airstream that will both protect the wing surface from the exhaust heat and reduce soot deposition.

Comment: So both comments and the answer answered my question, to whom do I give credit? I'd like to give each person due credit.

Comment: @Raffles This is why these sites discourage answers in comments (links to duplicates are a special case): we can't vote them up or down or give the author credit/rep.